# How to make Notification icon towards right in a Notification

Tags: javascript, push-notification

[Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwYC5.png)

I want to move the Notification Icon towards the right. It is a simple Notification created with -

```
new Notification("title", option{icon: `${icon-path}`})
```

For sample, one can check - https://web-push-book.gauntface.com/chapter-05/02-display-a-notification/#icon

Caution- I am not asking for Modal based Notification

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a runnable [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

```css
float:right
text-allign:right
```

simple float right to icon property